# javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator

Tags: spring-boot

I followed [this blog](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/) post and tried to implement a custom validator to validate a composite primary key constraint and it fails with:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: com.directory.domain.model.validators.StorePoolValidator.
    at com.directory.domain.repositories.StorePoolRepositoryTest.shouldReturnPoolByStore(StorePoolRepositoryTest.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.directory.domain.model.validators.StorePoolValidator.<init>()
    at com.directory.domain.repositories.StorePoolRepositoryTest.shouldReturnPoolByStore(StorePoolRepositoryTest.java:30)
```

Here is the code of the annotation interface of the validator:

```java
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD})
@Constraint(validatedBy = StorePoolValidator.class)
public @interface UniqueStorePoolConstraint {
    String message() default "Store pool validation failed";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Here is the validator class:

```java
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.List;

public class StorePoolValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueStorePoolConstraint, StorePoolId> {

    private StorePoolRepository storePoolRepository;

    public StorePoolValidator(StorePoolRepository storePoolRepository) {
        this.storePoolRepository = storePoolRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueStorePoolConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(StorePoolId id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final List<StorePool> storePools = storePoolRepository.findAllByStoreNumber(id.getThirdNumber());

        return storePools.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Here is the entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "STORE_POOLS")
public class StorePool implements Serializable {

    public StorePool() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @UniqueStorePoolConstraint
    private StorePoolId id;
}
```

and its primary key class:

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class StorePoolId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "pool", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Integer pool;

    @Column(name = "third_number", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Integer thirdNumber;
}
```

I tried to run the following test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class StorePoolRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private StorePoolRepository storePoolRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnPoolByStore() {
        final StorePool storePool = StorePoolBuilder.buildStorePool(1, 1);
        entityManager.persist(storePool);
        entityManager.flush();

        final List<StorePool> storePools = storePoolRepository.findAllByStoreNumber(1);

        assertThat(storePools).containsExactly(storePool);
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the very same question. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Shahin: sorry, I have no more access to the code source. You can try to implement the latest suggestions by Jonathan

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for being late in the discussion.

First of all create a **ContextProvider** which is the provider of bean that you need.

```
@Component
public class ContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ContextProvider.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(Class cls) {
        return ContextProvider.applicationContext.getBean(cls);
    }

}
```

Now you can have the bean like this way:

```
ContextProvider.getBean(StorePoolRepository.class);
```

That solves the NPE and you can have any component for your validation.

In your case **StorePoolValidator**,

```
@Service
public class StorePoolValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueStorePoolConstraint, StorePoolId> {

    private StorePoolRepository storePoolRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueStorePoolConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
         this.storePoolRepository = (StorePoolRepository) ContextProvider.getBean(StorePoolRepository.class) 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(StorePoolId id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final List<StorePool> storePools = storePoolRepository.findAllByStoreNumber(id.getThirdNumber());

        return storePools.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

I faced basically the same issue but with Mock testing and here's how I solved it:

1. Here is how my custom constraint validation looks like:

   Interface:

   ```
   @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameValidator.class)
   public @interface UniqueUsername {

    String message() default "This username is in use";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

   }
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

        private final UserRepository repository;

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            return !repository.existsById(username);
        }
   }
   ```
2. Annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest`
3. Set up MockMvc through Spring configuration:

   ```
   @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
   @SpringBootTest
   public class RegistrationTest {

       @Autowired
       private WebApplicationContext wac;

       private MockMvc mockMvc;

       @BeforeEach
       void setUp() {
           this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                   .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                   .alwaysDo(print())
                   .build();
       }

       // your tests

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do that for MockMvc.standalone()

Answer (score 2):

Need to be added a constructor empty by default `StorePoolValidator` in order to init the validator.

```
public StorePoolValidator() {
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order to use the repository, you can add the Validator as a service. Then the answer is this:

```
@Service
public class StorePoolValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueStorePoolConstraint, StorePoolId> {

    @Autowired
    private StorePoolRepository storePoolRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueStorePoolConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(StorePoolId id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final List<StorePool> storePools = storePoolRepository.findAllByStoreNumber(id.getThirdNumber());

        return storePools.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: The previous error has gone, but I have a NPE in `isValid` method -> `storePoolRepository` in `StorePoolValidator` class is null :(

Comment: @belgoros yes, I answered your first question, so the second one too I updated my answer, so let me know how it goes, kind regards.

Comment: @johntatn-jox Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, no changes, still the same NPE, no matter if I annotate `StorePoolValidator` with `@Service`, autowire `StorePoolRepository` or use an empty contructor as before: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException... at com...directory.validators.StorePoolValidator.isValid`

Comment: Ok in the test, add  @Autowired  private ApplicationContext context; , so let me know it, if not then could you please share a basic repo with this code so that I can help you?

Comment: No, it didn't solve the problem, even if autowiring the `ApplicationContext` in tests looks weird. I put the link to the blog article I followed to try to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I reviewed it, so you can fix adding @SpringBootTest after @RunWith(xxxx) that annotation will load the application context.

Comment: In my case, instead of addind an empty constructor, I have had to make the Validator public (it had package visibility) and now it can be instantiated on tests.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring framework automatically detects all classes which implement the  `ConstraintValidator` interface. The framework instantiates them and wires all dependencies like the class was a regular Spring bean. So you don't need to put `@Service` and `@Autowired` annotations.
[More details here.](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/)

Comment: Going through this Doloszewski's blog made me think the same, but the repository breaks it for me. Curently I get the same error, and it is all good when I get rid of the repo.
@belgoros seem to have the same problem