# Injected services become null in Custom Constraint Validators

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have tried to create a custom annotation with a constraint validator in the spring boot framework and I'm getting an error of injected services being null when executing the custom validator.

And, I have checked with the previous answers related to this. But, any answer didn't work for me now.

Some of them are as follows,

[javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204548/javax-validation-validationexception-hv000064-unable-to-instantiate-constraint)

[Autowired gives Null value in Custom Constraint validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958145/autowired-gives-null-value-in-custom-constraint-validator)

http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/

My custom annotation and constraint validator as follows,

**Custom Annotation**

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueFoodNameValidator.class)
public @interface UniqueFoodName {
    String message() default "{UniqueFoodName}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

**Custom Constraint Validator**

```
public class UniqueFoodNameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueFoodName, String> {

    private FoodService foodService;

    @Autowired
    public UniqueFoodNameValidator(FoodService foodService) {
        this.foodService = foodService;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueFoodName constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String foodName, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return Objects.isNull(foodName) || foodService.get(foodName).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

So, I would really appreciate If someone cloud help me to figure out the issue and to resolve this.

Note that: ***FoodService*** is an interface and it's methods implemented in the ***FoodServiceImpl*** class.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but hope it will be useful for someone.

I suppose the problem is in your Hibernate configuration. The thing is that you validate the field twice. It happens because both Spring and Hibernate run validation automatically.

If you debug `isValid` method, you will see the flow runs into the method twice first time your `FoodService` will be injected, but not the second time.

To fix it you can disable Hibernate auto validation. For example:

```
private Properties hibernateSettings() {
    Properties settings = new Properties();

    // some settings

    settings.put("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none");
    return settings;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateSettings());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.springmvc.models");
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```