# ConstraintValidator after migrating from Spring boot 2.7.15 -> 3.1.X

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I've been tasked to migrate to Spring Boot 3, so I'm taking the oportunity to simple update to the latest version. As I expected there are some migration pains that I have been dealing with. At the moment I'm stuck with the ConstraintValidators, I can't seem to find in any documentation any breaking changes but now it wants to have No Args constructors, so I checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/67515823/4902186 and went to a rabbit hole trying to make that work and decided against it (my unit tests got messed up and then I found a wierd behaviour that I'm explaining next).

For a brief time the errors I was getting from it wanting a no arg constructor (at runtime, it would compile and run properly) but then I noticed a couple of wierd things, validations would be triggered at the end of the API call (to be honest I'm unsure that was the case before but it's strange to me) and when it tried to persist (again, at the end of the call) it would do it at least twice and it'd throw a SQL exception stating that you cannot duplicate primary keys. Ultimately I am trying to look elsewhere but I'm unable to find anyone with this exact problem online.

So, here's an example of a validator that I'm having problems with:

```
@Component
public class CustomerAddressValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomerAddressValid, CustomerAddress> {

    private Map<CountryCode, Pattern> regexPatterns;

    @Autowired
    CustomerAddressValidator(ValidationProperties validationProperties) {
        regexPatterns = validationProperties.getZipcode().entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e1 -> CountryCode.valueOf(e1.getKey().toUpperCase()),
                        e2 -> Pattern.compile(Optional.ofNullable(e2.getValue())
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("zip code validation configuration failure for country code: " + e2.getKey())))));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomerAddressValid constraintAnnotation) {
        // Does not have a special initialization logic
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CustomerAddress address, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return allValid(isZipCodeValid(address, cxt),isAddressValid(address, cxt));
    }

    private boolean isZipCodeValid(CustomerAddress address, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        if (address == null || address.getZipCode() == null || address.getCountryCode() == null) return true;
        Pattern pattern = regexPatterns.get(address.getCountryCode());
        boolean isValid = pattern == null || pattern.matcher(address.getZipCode()).matches();
        if (!isValid)
            cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("zip code must match with pattern: " + pattern.toString())
                    .addPropertyNode("zipCode")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
        return isValid;
    }

    /**
     * Validates the combination of the address fields street, houseNumber and lineOne
     *
     * @param address the customer address
     * @param cxt     the validator context
     * @return true if the address rules are valid
     */
    private boolean isAddressValid(CustomerAddress address, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        String street = address.getStreet();
        String houseNumber = address.getHouseNumber();
        String lineOne = address.getLineOne();

        if ((street == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(street)) && (houseNumber == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(houseNumber)) && (lineOne == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(lineOne))) {
            cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Either the fields 'street' and 'houseNumber' must be filled or field 'lineOne'.")
                    .addPropertyNode("lineOne")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }


        if ((street == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(street)) && (houseNumber != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(houseNumber))) {
            cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("If the field 'houseNumber' is filled, please fill in the field 'street'.")
                    .addPropertyNode("houseNumber")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }

        if ((lineOne != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(lineOne)) && (street != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(street))) {
            cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Either the fields 'street' and 'houseNumber' must be filled or field 'lineOne'.")
                    .addPropertyNode("lineOne")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean allValid(Boolean... validations) {
        return Arrays.stream(validations).allMatch(isValid -> isValid);
    }
}
```

And here's the stack trace I get whenever I try to create a Customer, meaning I call one of the APIs using this validation:

```
jakarta.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: *.validation.CustomerAddressValidator.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:44) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.run(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:45) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.getInstance(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:29) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.newInstance(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:84) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.createAndInitializeValidator(AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:136) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:58) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint$TypeParameterValueReceiver.doValidate(MetaConstraint.java:246) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint$TypeParameterValueReceiver.indexedValue(MetaConstraint.java:212) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ListValueExtractor.extractValues(ListValueExtractor.java:28) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ListValueExtractor.extractValues(ListValueExtractor.java:17) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorHelper.extractValues(ValueExtractorHelper.java:42) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:117) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:635) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:364) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1375) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:303) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy204.findAllByCustomerId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at *.JpaCustomerService.toDto(JpaCustomerService.java:295) ~[classes/:na]
    at *.JpaCustomerService.createCustomer(JpaCustomerService.java:545) ~[classes/:na]
    at *.JpaCustomerService.createCustomer(JpaCustomerService.java:516) ~[classes/:na]
...
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: *.validation.CustomerAddressValidator.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:41) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]
    ... 197 common frames omitted
```

I'm looking for any light on this problem, why do I now appearantly need a No args constructor and how should I act on it.

Edit: this is not the only validation with this problem, but also I can't say for sure that every validation is failing.

Comment: Could you also update the question with `pom.xml` or `gradle.build`  file ?

Comment: Do you by any change configure the entitymanagerfactory yourself instead of using the spring auto configured one? Also yes it needs a default constructor and the field should be marked with the `@Autowired` annotation. This is kind of enforced by the specification. If configured properly it will still ask Spring to autowire the dependencies. It doesn't need to be an `@Component`. In short you cannot opt-out of the no-args constructor as that is what it needs to have according to the specification.

Comment: @AndreiLisa This project has got 4 pom files, it'd be easier to post only what you'd like to see

Comment: @M.Deinum No, I just checked no mention of any entitymanagerfactory in the whole project.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` run check if there are some `javax` dependencies

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment you simply need the no-args constructor. Add an `@Autowired` field and remove the `@Component`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm just trying that, but first, I had to change the field to the f Bean type of the cunstructor I was using before. The thing is that now, it's tekking me that Cannot invoke "com.tss.pago.core.validation.config.ValidationProperties.getZipcode()" because "this.validationProperties" is null, validation properties is the new field.

Comment: @AndreiLisa no javax dependencencies in the dependency tree

Comment: It is complaining **where**... Please don't describe code but instead **show code**. What did you do to modify it? And just making your curent constructor a no-arg constructor will fail!. What you have in your constructor needs to move to the `initialize` method instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry, that comment was clearly poorly written. That said, it's hard to show code in comments due to character number constraints. I did remove the `@Component` and added `@Autowired
    private ValidationProperties validationProperties;` as you suggested and got `Cannot invoke "*.validation.config.ValidationProperties.getZipcode()" because "this.validationProperties" is null`.  In the next comment I'll share the ValidationProperties.

Comment: `@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "validation")
public class ValidationProperties {
    Map<String, String> zipcode;
    Map<String, String> taxcode;
}`